# Razor View Extension Method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create an extension method which I can use in CSHTML file using @this, so I can have accesss to Layout and PageData properties in the method.

Now, what I want to know is which class to extend, I tried both StartPage and ViewStartPage.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to "extend"?

Comment: Good question, upon reading this again I'm not sure what you mean by "so I can have access to Layout and PageData".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the extension method to System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage. ViewStartPage and StartPage represent the _ViewStart.cshtml file (and _PageStart.cshtml in ASP.NET WebPages) respectively.

Comment: thanks dude WebViewPage works can you explain more about the _PageStart

Answer (score 1):

Hallo,

If I understand it right a HTML helper method could help you.

You could pass as a parameter all variables you have in your page.

```
@Html.ShowMyText(Model.YourStringToUse)
```

And in your helper method you can do your logic and return something what should be rendered.
(My be you can also modify some things in your helper.ViewContext object.

Your Html-helper could look like this:

```
public static HtmlString ShowMyText(this HtmlHelper helper,string pourStringToUse)
{ 
     CultureInfo cultureInfo = (CultureInfo)helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Session["CurrentLanguage"];

    if (cultureInfo.IetfLanguageTag.Equals("en-EN") == true)
    {
        return new HtmlString("English");
    }
    else
    {
        return new HtmlString("Not English");
    }
}
```

So maybe it gives you a starting point. Anyway, it's possible that you don't have access to everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the `WebPageBase` class, which all Razor views inherit.